# Constructing 5 by 5 Unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, random-matrices

I am trying to construct an arbitrary 5 x 5 Unitary matrix.
Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: Pick any orthonormal basis $v_1,\ldots,v_5$ for $\mathbb C^5$ and put $M=[v_1,\ldots,v_5]$.

Comment: If all you want is an example, the $5\times5$ identity matrix will do.

Comment: Do you mean that you want an *algorithm* to construct such a matrix?

Comment: Given that you have put the tags (quantum-mechanics) and (random-matrices), are you interested in ways of generating unitary random matrices from the "uniform" distribution (i.e., Haar measure) on the space of $5\times 5$ unitary matrices?

Comment: Yes please @PierreYvesGaudreauLamarre.

Answer (score 1):

An example: the identity matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
}
$$
Alternatively, take any *permutation matrix*, which can be made by rearranging these columns

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,
the *standard* way of generating a haar unitary matrix is through the QR decomposition.

For any matrix $A$ with complex coefficients,
there exists a unitary matrix $Q$ and an upper triangular matrix $R$ such that $QR=A$ (see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) article). Furthermore,
under certain conditions on $A$,
$Q$ can be Haar distributed.

A simple MATLAB implementation of an algorithm for generating a $5\times 5$ Haar matrix in this way is given by Edelman and Rao in the paper "Random matrix theory" ([link](http://stuff.mit.edu/people/raj/Acta05rmt.pdf)) as follows:

```
 % Generate Haar unitary matrix
 [Q,R]=qr(randn(5)+i*randn(5));
 Q=Q*diag(exp(i*2*pi*rand(5,1)));
```

which basically translates as

1. Generate a $5\times 5$ matrix $A_1$ whose entries are i.i.d. copies of $N(0,1)$ random variables;
2. Generate a $5\times 5$ matrix $A_2$ whose entries are i.i.d. copies of $N(0,1)$ random variables;
3. Let $A=A_1+iA_2$;
4. Let $QR=A$ be the QR decomposition of $A$;
5. Multiply $Q$ by the matrix $$
   D=\pmatrix{
   e^{i2\pi x_1}&0&0&0&0\\
   0&e^{i2\pi x_2}&0&0&0\\
   0&0&e^{i2\pi x_3}&0&0\\
   0&0&0&e^{i2\pi x_4}&0\\
   0&0&0&0&e^{i2\pi x_5}\\
   }
   $$
   where $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ are independent random variables from the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$;
6. $U=QD$ is a Haar unitary random matrix.

For a detailed explanation of why this algorithm works (especially, why we need step 5),
see section "4.6. Haar-distributed orthogonal, unitary and symplectic eigenvectors" in the paper of Edelman and Rao.